# TCL REST how to set HTTP Header

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to connect to a REST API  with tcl.
I'm using [rest from tcllib](https://tools.ietf.org/doc/tcllib/html/rest.html#synopsis)

I have read through the whole documentation but it seems like I'm not able to figure out how to set custom HTTP Header.

For example:

**"X-TEST-HEADER: HEADER"**

or

**"X-USER-ID: 12345"**

notes: 
totally new to TCL

so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is hard to read (due to a bug in the renderer for the docs) but you specify custom headers via the optional *config* dictionary:

```
rest::get $url {} {
    headers {
        X-USER-ID 12345
        X-TEST-HEADER "HEADER"
    }
}
```

You can create the configuration dynamically by using `dict`:

```
set userid 12345
dict set config headers X-USER-ID $userid
dict set config headers X-TEST-HEADER "This is a longer sample..."
rest::get $url {} $config
```